# Programmatically change a Google apps script's timezone

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I've been having a very hard time trying to properly set up the timezones of [calendar event dates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date)) because the Javascript's Date object is taking the project's timezone:

[image: Project properties].

Is there a way to programmatically change that property?

Comment: No. The project time zone can not be changed with code.  You can *get* the script time zone `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` with code, but you can not *set* it with code.  You shouldn't be changing the script time zone in code anyway.   I'm assuming that you have users who are in different time zones?  If there are multiple users of the script in different time zones, then I set the Time Zone in the script to **+GMT 00:00 no daylight savings.**  And leave it at that.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Sandy!

Comment: @SandyGood Worked like a charm! You can post this one as an answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The project time zone can not be changed with code. You can get the script time zone Session.getScriptTimeZone() with code, but you can not set it with code. You shouldn't be changing the script time zone in code anyway. I'm assuming that you have users who are in different time zones? If there are multiple users of the script in different time zones, then I set the Time Zone in the script to +GMT 00:00 no daylight savings. And leave it at that.