# Programmatically change a Google apps script's timezone

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been having a very hard time trying to properly set up the timezones of [calendar event dates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date)) because the Javascript's Date object is taking the project's timezone:

[image: Project properties].

Is there a way to programmatically change that property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically change a Google apps script's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336869/programatically-change-a-google-apps-scripts-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using date time formatting. Here is an example

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[0][12]), "GMT+5", "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy")
```

You can mention your time zone instead of "GMT+5".

Comment: data[0][12] is an array index. You can use your date object instead. Like   new Date() for current date time.